# Handling different Spring Boot versions in custom Spring Boot Autoconfiguration projects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

In custom Spring Boot Autoconfiguration projects I usually have some dependencies which are marked as optional. As I need them for compilation, but expect users of my autoconfig to include them manually in their own POM, or they will be provided by the Spring Boot dependencies.

How do I ensure that users of different Spring Boot versions can use my autoconfig without dependecy/version problems?

I see two non-optimal solutions; are there more?

#### Hoping that the API stays the same

Just hope that the API of my dependencies stays stable over minor version changes, so that if I developed and compiled my Autoconfig e.g. with Spring Boot 1.4.x, the API which I used is still the same with 1.5.x, etc.

I then wouldn't necessarily expect it to work e.g. for Spring Boot 2.x, and would put a corresponding note into the readme.

#### Explicitly tracking each Spring Boot version

Explicitly build a version for at least each minor Spring Boot version, but possibly even for each Patch version? Who knows when a breaking API change could happen. I would then need to document for which exact Spring Boot version my autoconfig is intended. But this is a lot of work.

---

Of course Spring Boot's own autoconfig project is developed in lockstep with Spring Boot, so that any problems will be fixed in the same release.

But my own autoconfig might have been developed once and not expect many changes afterwards. **How do I ensure that my autoconfig keeps working as long as possible even as the "users" of my autoconfig are updating their Spring Boot version dependencies?**